# Using Java annotations in Maven multi-module projects

Tags: java, maven, preprocessor, multi-module

A common use case for me is that I need to deploy multiple Java applications/customizations into customer environments. Often these different parts have to be developed as separate Maven projects where each project contains/produces multiple files of various types (jar, JSP, properties, XML etc). A lot of these extra files are generated via the use of Java annotations and the preprocessor functionality.

The problem I'm facing is that multiple projects may produce the same files which must then be merged together and it is becoming increasingly harder to do this as the number of submodules go up. The result being that I may mess up the merging and create either invalid or incomplete files which are then deployed causing problems in the target environment. Not to mention that this manual merging process makes it impossible to automate the builds.

I'm looking for a way to structure my projects or for plugins (or some other way) that may help, so that I can have an aggregator project that can collect all these files from all the projects and merge them into final versions that contains the contributions from each individual submodule. The goal is of course that building some sort of top project will result in a complete deployment package that can be directly installed without any further manual processing.

A good approach could have been if the aggregator project could run preprocessing on all annotations from all the submodules and simply create the finished files but as far as I understand how the preproccesor this is not really an option.

Do you know of any technique, plugin or something else that could help me accomplish this?

Comment: Could you please create a small but fully functional example showing the problem you have and put it on e.g. github?  Right now it is not easy to guess exactly what you are working with.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help out! I've added three new repos to illustrate the issue: [test-aggregator](https://github.com/dsodling/test-aggregator), [test-parent](https://github.com/dsodling/test-parent) and [test-pre-processor](https://github.com/dsodling/test-pre-processor).  The idea is that the pre-processor creates the file _xconf.properties_ in both sub modules and I would like to merge these to files in the aggregator project when I build it.